References on solid sequence spaces
I have been trying to search in different books on functional analysis for examples and properties of solid sequence spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_set), however I cannot find any reference with a collection of robust examples and some characterisations. I would appreciate very much your help if you can provide me with some references, books or articles where I can find this information. I was able to find a pretty good treatise on sequence spaces in this book: Sequence Spaces Topics in Modern Summability Theory; but it does not discuss several examples in my opinion.
